# POST Request remake from Python to Java

Tags: java, python, apache, python-requests, httpclient

### I need to remake next code from Python to Java:

```
import requests
import base64

def search(api_token, image):
    endpoint="https://trace.moe/api/search"
    params={"token":api_token}
    data={"image":image}
    r = requests.post(endpoint, params=params, data=data)
    if r.status_code==403:
        raise Exception("API token invalid")
    elif r.status_code==401:
        raise Exception("API token missing")
    elif r.status_code==413:
        raise Exception("The image is too large, please reduce the image size to below 1MB")
    elif r.status_code==429:
        raise Exception("You have exceeded your quota. Please wait and try again soon.")
    elif r.status_code==200:
        return(r.json())

with open("test.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

search = search("token", encoded_string)
```

I've tried to use Apache HttpClient with MultipartEntity, but it didn't help me.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://trace.moe/api/search");
File file = getImgFile();

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile);


httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
    resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Any my try give "No data received" or empty "docs".
What i can do?

Comment: Your title says you are to remake from java to python, and your post says you want to remake from python to java, Please make up your mind and edit the post :)

Comment: `https://whatanime.ga/api/search` is not a valid link either

Comment: srr, my mistake. updated

Comment: Alright, I will go ahead and see what I can do.

Comment: Can you link me the site where I can generate the api token?

Comment: Token isn't required param, you can call api without him.

Comment: Hey you should look over to the answer I posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a few minutes of keyboard bashing I have made the code that works with it, But it does not handle the request code and does not handle the actual JSON, You will need to implement it, It prints out the response for now. This is a basic start for what you wanna do. here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Rab\\Desktop\\lol\\anime.jpg");
    try {
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        String imageData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
        search("", imageData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void search(String token, String image){
    try {
        String urlParameters = String.format("token=%s&image=%s", token, image);
        byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        URL url = new URL("https://trace.moe/api/search");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.addRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(postData);
        }
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String wtf = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(wtf);

        //Handle your data `wtf` is the response of the server


    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the imports

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Base64;
```

Side note: anime.jpg is [image]